# Unexpected Json.NET exception when using MemberSerialization.OptIn and Required.Always

Tags: c#, json.net

I have declared a model class that has some properties to be populated by JSON and some that will be populated by code, indicated by the [JsonObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) and [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attributes. Here is a simplified version:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn, ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class AppCard
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public bool IsInstalled { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the JSON from my unit test:

```
[
  {
    "name": "App 1",
    "author": "Author 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "App 2",
    "author": "Author 2"
  }
]
```

And here is where I call [DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm):

```
appCards = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<AppCard>>(content);
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Required property 'IsInstalled'
not found in JSON. Path '[0]', line 5, position 3.
```

Since that property does not have the JsonProperty attribute and OptIn is specified, I assumed the DeserializeObject method would ignore it. Have I misunderstood how these settings are supposed to work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a bug to me.  In stepping through the code, Json.Net marks unadorned properties as ignored if the `MemberSerialization` is set to `OptIn`, but then does not honor the ignored status when doing the check for required properties.  The same thing happens if you use `OptOut` serialization (the default), mark the object as having required properties and then explicitly mark a property with `[JsonIgnore]`:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class AppCard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsInstalled { get; set; }
}
```

It's possible this was by design, but it seems to violate the "principle of least surprise".  You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

As a workaround, just mark the individual properties as required via the `[JsonProperty]` attribute instead of setting that option on the class.  Since you've already got all your properties marked with `[JsonProperty]` anyway (by virtue of using `OptIn`), it should be easy enough to add the `Required` option with find and replace.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class AppCard
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public bool IsInstalled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought it might be a bug (or close) - thanks for digging through it and confirming! And thanks for the workaround - it's very clean as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying that `ItemRequired = Required.Always`,

**According to the documentation:**

[*Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the object's properties are required.*](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute_ItemRequired.htm)

And your `IsInstalled` member is effectively a property.

Some options in `JsonObject` are mutually exclusive though [not explicitly stated](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm).

Comment: Why would DeserializeObject treat IsInstalled as a required property when it's explicitly excluded from serialization?

Comment: Well we can't tell for sure unless one looks at the source but I'd say that `ItemRequired` has precedence over `MemberSerialization.OptIn`.